# MySQL not pushing insert into database with netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets, netbeans

Recently I'm just learning some HTML, JSP and servlets for a university project, the thing is that I made a database into MySQL Workbench with id primary key, auto increment , then some fields like username, password, firstname, lastname, and so on.

The goal is to make a login page and register page, for some reason if I push data with MySQL Workbench into the database it will let me retrieve it with my login form and my select statment, but for some reason I'm doing the same thing with register but in this case with the query INSERT.

So, after research, I did preparestatment and changed the executeQuery to executeUpdate and everything, but my log says a nullPointerException somewhere, I know it may be a simple and silly error that I'm not seeing, but I'm new at this. This is what U have made so far to insert data into my database:

```
public static UserBean registarUsuario(UserBean bean){

            //preparing some objects for connection 
     Statement stmt = null;    
     ResultSet rs = null;  

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error al cargar el driver");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

     String firstname = bean.getFirstName();    
     String lastname = bean.getLastName(); 
     String username = bean.getUsername();    
     String password = bean.getPassword();   
     boolean admin = bean.isAdmin(); 
     int tipo = bean.getType(); 
        String insertQuery =
           "insert into idusuario (firstname,lastname,username,password,admin,tipo) values ('"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+username+"','"+password+"','"+admin+"','"+tipo+"')";

        System.out.println("Firstname is " + firstname);          
  System.out.println("Surname is " + lastname);
  System.out.println("Query: "+insertQuery);

  try 
  {
     //connect to DB 
     currentCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuarios", "root", "admin");
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(insertQuery);
...
```

My output:

> Info:   Query: insert into idusuario
>   (firstname,lastname,username,password,admin,tipo) values
>   ('jhon','marston','jmar','123','true','0') Info: Error :
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

The thing is that Netbeans doesn't even tell me where the NPE is happening so I'm kind of confused, I don't know if the query is wrong or if something else is, because as I can see in my output, the query seems ok.

I leave you here my database structure

[image]

Comment: Try to use `ex.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` in your `catch` blocks.

Comment: @Ivan thanks buddy, it really helped me out to see better the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigining the `stmt` as null and never initializing it.

```
 Statement stmt = null;    
 ResultSet rs = null;
```

Then you are trying to use it:

```
 rs = stmt.executeQuery(insertQuery);
```

You will need to do something [like this](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface) before you use it:

```
PreparedStatement stmt=currentCon.prepareStatement(yourQuery);
```

Comment: its weird because in my login method i had initialized it the same way and its working fine, i  knew something was wrong with it but its kind of weird whats happening

Comment: @GastónSaillén you also need to use `stmt.executeUpdate(query)` as `INSERT` statement doesn't generate `ResultSet`

Comment: oh wait i think i know what it is

Comment: finally solved my problem, thanks a bunch for all the help !

Answer (score 1):

> So, after research, i did preparestatment and changed the executeQuery
>   to executeUpdate and everything, but my log says a
>   nullPointerException somewhere, i know it may be a simple and silly
>   error that im not seeing, but understand that im new at this. this is
>   what i have made so far to insert data into my database

When we use `insert`,`update` or `delete` we need to use `executeUpdate`.
When we use `select` we need to use `executeQuery`.

In your example you are doing `executeQuery` for an `insert`. **This is wrong**. You need to use this:

```
rs = stmt.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
```

You're getting a NPE because you are trying to retrieve the results where there are none.

Here is a nice thing to do to help you reduce boilerplate code... (so you don't have to keep repeating yourself with db initialization values)

Create a class for your database connection:

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static String url = null;
    private static Connection conn = null;
     public static Connection getConnection(){
     try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuarios";
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","admin");
     }   catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
     return conn;
     }
}
```

Now you can use this in all your other classes like this:

```
public static UserBean registarUsuario(UserBean bean){
          try(Connection conn= DBConnection.getConnection()){
              PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into idusuario (firstname,lastname,username,password,admin,tipo) values (?,?,?,?,?,?);");  
              pst.setString(1, bean.getFirstName());
              pst.setString(2, bean.getLastName());
              pst.setString(3, bean.getUserName());
              pst.setString(4, bean.getPassword());
              pst.setBoolean(5, bean.isAdmin());
              pst.setInt(6, bean.getType());
                pst.executeUpdate();    
          }catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```